# Understanding the 'Truncated DFT' for Moiré Phase Analysis

Tags: fourier-transform, geometric-optics, experimental-technique

I am researching the use of a Moiré sampling algorithm in order to determine the two-dimensional displacement field of an object. In [the paper of Wang and Ri (2022)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2095034922000071), the algorithm is described. Attached you find my interpretation of the step I do not really understand:

[image: My understanding of the algorithm to determine the phase field of an image]

First, Moiré fringes are obtained by sampling and consequently interpolating the original (deformed) grating image *T* times (where *T* is the closest positive integer to the wavelength of the grating in pixels). The *T* images represent the moire pattern obtained by superimposing the grating by a version shifted *k(2π/Τ)* for *k ∈ [0,T]*. This part I understand

Then, the phase-field of the initial image is determined by performing something that looks like a truncated Fourier series along the sampled Moiré fringes: The argument of the sum of these Moiré fringes is then assumed to be directly proportional to the phase distribution of the image.

Could someone maybe explain the meaning of these 'Fourier-like' components to me, and how the argument of their sum could be related to the phase distribution of the image?

P.S. This is my first post on Stack Exchange, so please tell me how I can improve!